# Highcharts "synchronized-charts" module won't load data from locally placed "activity.json" file

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, highcharts

Trying to run/test the synchronized-chart highcharts module from the required data file (activity.json) which is on my local hard drive.  All other code in the module is unchanged from the original highcharts demo.  The chart will not display when I change the call to the highcharts server to the call to my hard drive.  Any help with what else I need to adjust will be much appreciated

I've searched for a solution to this for several hours.  Unfortunately other similar problems were pre-ajax utilization.  I've also ensured that the format of my json file (an exact duplicate of the file on Highcharts server) is correct using a validator tool in addition to an eyeball comparison.

…
// Get the data. The contents of the data file can be viewed at
Highcharts.ajax({
url:'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highcharts/highcharts@v7.0.0/samples/data/activity.json',

```
dataType: 'text',
success: function (activity) {
```

...

The chart works with the above URL, but DOESN'T work when I replace that URL with my local URL where the file resides.  My replacement URL:

url:'C:\Users\IggyB\OneDrive\Desktop\PortalTestFiles\ChartsCode\data\activity.json'

Comment: Confused as to why that comment and top line of code came out in the text portion...I entered it into the code area of the question setup.  Bottom line, trying to replace this url with my own:

Comment: Highcharts.ajax({ url:'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highcharts/highcharts@v7.0.0/samples/data/activity.json',

Comment: Why do you want to load the JSON from your local system directly to the browser? If you want to test things without a server you can always use services to host your test JSON file like `http://myjson.com/`, tools like eg. `require.js` or just load the data in the head of your HTML document.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas Wojciech. The reason for a local load is to test the ability to execute with our data, and the usefulness of the selected chart with same. The environment is an internal intranet and the data would eventually sit on an network server or a SharePoint repository. The point is to test the feasibility without requirement for the “www” component. So that rules out json.com (for this test anyway).

Comment: Using require.js would require a lengthy vetting process before introducing to the environment as well. My base question was what code adjustments are required to simply call a JSON file locally, in the same manner as I’m able to, say, reference highcharts.js locally? Dropping the data in the head doesn’t solve that because it doesn’t test the data call. Not sure how to adjust this code to do that anyway, without a substantial effort.